# Converting lists in a column into an array

Tags: arrays, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe with 2 columns and would like to convert the entries of one of the columns, called "Features", which are as a list of numbers, into an array-like object. I have tried different numpy function by dealing directly with the column and putting the result of the operation into a new column but the result is still the same: I am still getting a list of numbers for each entry.

I tried iterating over the rows of that column using iterrows while appending to a list, since it was raising an error for me of unmatching length with the index, but that also gave me the same result:

```
f_list = []
#converting features to a numpy array 
for index, row in df_balanced.iterrows():
    f_array = np.array(row["features"])
    print(f_array)
    f_list.append(f_array)
df_balanced['features_array']=f_list
```

Any help would be appreciated. Here's an image to my [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o5pA.png)

Comment: Give us a small sample dataframe, so we know exactly what you have.  The description and image aren't enough.

Comment: How do you know it hasn't changed?  The display of list and arrays (and strings) is the same in a dataframe.  Take a look at `df_balanced[col].values` to see a `numpy` display of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't rely on a loop, but I think it will do what you want.

I took the liberty to create a test dataframe:

```
d1 = {'id': [1, 2, 3],
      'features': [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 3,], [9, 2, 9]]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
```

here we convert the features to a numpy array:

```
ar = np.array(df1.features.tolist(), dtype=np.float32)
```

then we add it as a DataFrame column, using the Series constructor:

```
df1["features_array"] = pd.Series(list(ar))
```

Comment: the `ar` variable contains the array of every row but adding it to a new column is giving me a NaN value in my case or staying as a list in your example. Thank you.

Comment: it appears like a list only when you look at the dataframe, if access a specific value of the column `features_array`using the methods `.loc` or `.iloc` you would see it as an array.

Comment: for example using this `df1.loc[0, "features_array"]` would give you  `array([1., 2., 3.], dtype=float32)` and `df1.loc[0, "features"]` would give you `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: as for the NaN issue, I need you to provide me with code and data I can use to reproduce the error.

Comment: if I access a specific value it's still giving me a list for your example: 
`print(type(df1.features_array[0]))
<class 'list'>`

Comment: You are doing something different than what I posted, running `print(type(df1.features_array[0])) ` still gives me the following output `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: you were right it was actually producing a 'numpy.ndarray'. The remaining problem is that it's producing a NaN value in the respective column being created. Here's a sample from my data https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5b4401a9f7b2c9e9330c70ec04cf242520210306231828/aa49b0